# when retake photo -> photo is not saved to the file

Tags: android, xamarin

From inside of my app I start 'camera app'.
Camera is configured such that taken photo is saved to the file.

Code starting camera [Xamarin, but problem is general]:

```
var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, properAndroidUriPointingFile);
this.StartActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE_PHOTO_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Now: if user: takes photo, presses "save" [in the camera app], and returns to my app -> it just saves photo to pointed [in above intent] file. It just works fine.

But if user: takes photo, press "cancel" [in the camera app], takes photo again, presses "save" -> the file is not created.

Looks like a problem in Android's camera app.
I am testing it on Galaxy Note 10. Android 4.1.2.

Any ideas for workaround?

Comment: did you test it on an other device? or in the emulator? (if you have a webcam)

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm or not whether this is a bug. But a possible work-around could be for your app to request the image-data instead of asking the camera app to store it for you. Then your app could store it by itself.